# how to use angularjs promise?

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to make an animation on an html table.

i use `$interval` to display each row one by one.

```
var loadList = function() {
    Obj.query(function(obj){
        $scope.objs = [];
        $interval(function() {$scope.objs.push(obj.shift())}, 200, obj.length);
    });
}
```

then there is a function to remove each row one by one, 
and finally it's looping and reload the table again :

```
var cleanList = function() {
    var delay = 200; 
    var n = $scope.objs.length;

        if (n!==0) {
            $interval(function() {$scope.objs.shift()}, delay, n);
        }
        $interval(function() { loadList() }, delay*n, 1);
    }

loadList();
$interval(cleanList, 7000);
```

The code is working here (here is [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2vkQ17?p=preview)), but i guess there is a way to do something nicer with a kind of "callback" or "promise" to trigger when the cleanList function is completed ?

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$interval returns a promise so you can simply call `then()` on it.

For example:

```
$interval(function() {$scope.objs.push(obj.shift())}, 200, obj.length).then(cleanList);
```

Here's a working plunkr example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rYzXjM?p=preview